# How browser authenticate user from stored username and password?

Tags: javascript, python, authentication, browser

I want to know how the browser authenticates user from stored username and password. Friend of mine want to develop website in which she wants to store username and password(Of Gmail, Yahoo, etc) in database and when the user clicks on the particular button the user should be authenticated every time by fetching the username and password from the database and providing it to the particular website. I am confused what to do. Can anyone suggest me the ways?

What I have done:
First thought : I searched for [Digestive Access Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) Do web browsers authenticate in this way? If it is then I was thinking to request particular URL by [XMLHTTPREQUEST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) but unable to do because of [SameOriginPolicy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). I have also tried by xmlHttpRequestObj.withCredentials = true but the response header is not allowed.[CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

I want your suggestions that in how many ways I can achieve my goal. I field in the way I was thinking. Thank you in advance.:)

Comment: Imho that is a pretty bad thing to do (the storing of user credentials of other services). Can't you just use the public APIs of the services instead for your use case?

Comment: I am highly agree on your suggestion. But that was the obvious and last thing. As I have asked in my question I want to think in how many ways I can solve this problem is main focus of mine.

Comment: Browsers don't authenticate, web servers do.

Comment: Please be careful! If you make this site without sufficient expertise in website and database security techniques very Bad Things could happen.

Comment: @stark I know but It will be more help full if you share that how the browser able to provide username and password to particular web server and give direct access to user.

Comment: @PM2Ring That is second step. First I want to know that is it possible ? if it is then How ?

Comment: Maybe this will help get you started: [Authentication with Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/)